# how to login/SignUp to a webserver from iphone applicaton

Tags: iphone

I wan the following functionality in my iphone application

1. User Register/signup form my application to the website(mysql/php)
2. User login to the site from application.
3. User write comment on pictures from application.

   Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to extend your website to support some flavor of web service (REST, SOAP, etc)  Then your app can simply call the web service methods to do the various operations you listed.